# How can I parse yaml comments using java?

Tags: java, parsing, jackson, yaml, comments

I want to use a yml configuration file in my project. I am using `jackson-dataformat-yaml` for parsing yml files. But I need to parse yml comments as well. I used the similar approach in python using `ruamel yaml`. How can I do the same in java?

**Upd.**

What for? Well, I wanted to make it possible to override my configuration options by using command line arguments. So, to generate description message for each option, I wanted to use my comments. Like this:

In my `config.yml`

```
# Define a source directory
src: '/foo/bar'

# Define a destination directory
dst: '/foo/baz'
```

So when you run your program with the `--help` flag, you'll see the following output:

```
Your program can be ran with the following options: 
--src   Define a source directory
--dst   Define a destination directory
```

The main benefit in such a model is that you don't ever need to repeat the same statement twice, because they can be retrieved from the configuration file.

Comment: You don't because YAML defines that comments must not convey content information and therefore, if you process comments in any way, you are violating the YAML spec. On the more pragmatic side, SnakeYaml, which is used by Jackson under the hood, does not support it. But perhaps this is an XY problem and if you describe your use-case, there might be alternatives (like e.g. using YAML tags).

Comment: @flyx I've just added my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have three layers of data:

- Your configuration schema. This defines the values that are to be defined in the configuration file.
- The configuration file itself, which describes the usual configuration on the current machine.
- One-time switches, which override the usual configuration.

The descriptions of what each value does belong to the schema, not to the configuration file itself. Think about it: If someone edits the configuration file on their machine and changes the comments, your help output would suddenly show different descriptions.

My suggestion would be to add the descriptions to the schema. The schema is the Java class you load your YAML into. I am not sure why you are using Jackson, since it uses SnakeYaml as parser and SnakeYaml is perfectly able to deserialize into Java classes, but has more configuration options since it does not generalize over JSON *and* YAML like Jackson does.

Here's a general idea how to do it with SnakeYaml (beware, untested):

```
// ConfigParam.java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ConfigParam { String description(); }

// Configuration.java
public class Configuration {
    @ConfigParam("Define a source directory")
    String src;
    @ConfigParam("Define a destination directory")
    String dst;
}

// loading code
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Configuration.class));
Configuration config = yaml.loadAs(input, Configuration.class);

// help generation code
System.out.println("Your program can be ran with the following options:")
for (Field field: Configuration.class.getFields()) {
    ConfigParam ann = field.getAnnotation(ConfigParam.class);
    if (ann != null) {
        System.out.println(String.format("--%s  %s", field.getName(), ann.description());
    }
}
```

For mapping actual parameters to the configuration, you can also loop over class fields and map the parameters to the field names *after* having loaded the configuration (to replace the standard values with the given ones).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've just been too relaxed after ruby :) I wrote almost just the same code as you did. Thanks a lot for a complete explanation.